# How to compress images in Base 64 with Node.js, lambda function

Tags: javascript, node.js, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, serverless-framework

I want to compress images sent by the client side in Base 64 and pass to AWS to Store in S3 service. But my problem is that the images are a lot so we want to compress the size of the images, but to AWS we send a base 64 data which contains the image so I want to apply an algorithm or a library in the Lambda function which compress the size of the image.

The problem is not working with paths because there are libraries which do that. I need a library for doing the compress via algorithm or functions. Then it is stored in S3 so I should not have a decompress algorithm in another lambda function.

I am working with nodejs and serverless for the lambdas.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Why are you using base64!?  You're wasting 33% in size, and extra memory usage.

Answer (score 0):

We do image processing using Lambda with nodejs. One of the main functionality is to compress the images down to reasonable size. What you need is to add ImageMagick as a Lambda Layer to compress the images on receiving them and upload to your S3 bucket.

Here's one such library you can use as a Lambda layer [https://serverlessrepo.aws.amazon.com/applications/arn:aws:serverlessrepo:us-east-1:145266761615:applications~image-magick-lambda-layer](https://serverlessrepo.aws.amazon.com/applications/arn:aws:serverlessrepo:us-east-1:145266761615:applications%7Eimage-magick-lambda-layer)

Comment: libvips via Sharp is more efficient.